# React Native upgrade from 0.59.10 to 0.63

Tags: react-native, textinput

While upgrading from React Native 0.59.10 to 0.63.2 I followed this
`https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.59.10&to=0.63.2`

Now I am getting below error

```
ERROR    TypeError: Object is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _reactNative.TextInput()')
ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

I tried on google to find the issue but with no success. Please help

Thanks

Comment: Upgrading a react-native version always is a mess. Can you try creating a new react-native project and copy the Android and Ios folder to your out-of-date project? Change your react-native and React version on `package.json` as well. make sure to only test this solution.

Comment: have you resolved this issue? I'm also stuck in this same situation right now. It comes when we remove MainReactPackage from MyApplicaiton.java

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't risk going directly from 0.59.* to 0.63.*. It's safer to gradually upgrade through all major versions, checking if smth got broken along the way.

Alternatively, As Wiliam Brochensque junior wrote, you can create a new project of version 0.63.* and move all of your source code files from the old one. Keep in mind though, that the old project can contain different settings here and there, which you will also have to transfer.